# Software to make a radial genealogy tree

Tags: java, diagram, genealogy

I want to make a genealogy tree with this style (radial ) like this:

[image]
<sup>Click image for larger variant</sup>

I first tried to do it with Photoshop but I don't really master it and my family has about 100 members.  I wondered if isn't there a Java library  to do that because I know the language. But I've found nothing.

I use Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. It would be better if I can do it in Java but if there is a free software, it's also convenient.
Some friends advised me to do it in JavaScript but I don't know the language. So if there is a software to do that, I'd like to know it.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: What OS should the software run on? What is your price limit? Should it just get you that chart, or are there any other features you need (must have or optional)? Maybe a full-fledged Genealogy software like [Gramps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramps)? And must it be in Java (as the tag suggests)? Please **[edit]** your question to fill these gaps. Thanks!

Comment: If you cannot do the programming yourself, it won't help you if we'd recommend libraries. You'd need something ready-to-use. I already mentioned Gramps, which is free and available cross-platform. They don't seem to have "sun charts", but their "fan charts" might come close. [See here](https://www.gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=Features) for features and screenshots. Hopefully someone can come up with a software offering sun charts, good luck!

Comment: Does the site MyHeritage.com not offer it anymore or did it became a paid feature? Is there something else that is preventing you from generating it there? Maybe data/info privacy? Because in the beginning it was free, but I don't know if that changed over the years.

Comment: In fact I don't use MyHeritage.com, I wanted to do this genealogy tree with this style and it was the only image that I found on the web. And yes visibly you need to pay to have that

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a non-java app, have a look at [Webtrees](https://github.com/fisharebest/webtrees).

- It is opensource (php/mysql) and you can run it on a Windows or Linux machine.
- It supports a fan/radial chart via this [plugin](https://github.com/magicsunday/webtrees-fan-chart)